# How to read a string in mips that is multiple characters

Tags: mips, computer-science

I found this code:

```
.data
   buffer: .space 20

...
_readString:
        li $v0, 8           # Syscall 8: Read string
        la $a0, buffer          # load byte space into address
        addi $a1, $zero, 20         # allot the byte space for string
        syscall
        jr   $ra
```

But I don't understand it. What are the `la` and the `addi` lines doing? Does a buffer space of 20 mean 20 characters?

I found similar code in my class's tutorial of MIPS:

```
li $v0, 8 - syscall code for reading a string
la $a0, buffer - load buffer address into register
li $a1, 20 - max. bytes for syscall to read
move $t0, $a0 - move string to $t0 to do something with it
syscall
```

But why does the move of $a0 (the presumed place where the string is going to be stored) occur before the syscall? Why does that make sense?

Comment: _"why does the move of $a0 (the presumed place where the string is going to be stored) occur before the syscall?"_ How else is the system call going to know where to store the characters? System call 8 doesn't allocate memory itself; it relies on the caller to provide it with the address of some memory where the characters can be stored.

Comment: Isn't it just stored in $a0?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. A string can't fit in a register, unless every string is going to be 4 characters or less.

Comment: So how does this work? Does it continuously move data from a0 to t0?

Comment: No. You can think of it as multiple people having the combination to a safe, and the registers being post-it notes where they have written down the combination. Just because someone puts something into the safe, it won't change the combination or what is written on the post-its.

Comment: I guess I don't get it. How could the move happen before the syscall? There's no string in $a0 yet?

Comment: And there never will be. `$a0` will not contain the string itself; it's just used to pass the address of the memory where the string will be stored. In this case it's the address of `buffer`.

Comment: Oh I see, it's a reference to an address that's why we can move it before or after.

Comment: oh I see, la loads the address and not the value at the address right?